# move the vertical position of an image as a link without moving the link itself

Tags: image, css, hyperlink

I have two links which are using an image as a link. These images strangely are placed a bit higher than excepted, as you can see in this picture:

[image]

I want to move these images some pixels under so its aligned with the rest of the text. I've used `margin-top` and `padding-top` addressing with this path `#foot-content a img`. But when I moved them they simply move all the rest of the text downwards. Under I place my html of my footer if handy. Could you let me know what solution is there?

```
<footer>    
            <div id="footer-bg-left">
                <div id="foot-content">
                    <p>Diseñado por <a href="mailto:hola@escuderodesign.com">Daniel. R-Escudero</a> <span>|</span> Todos los derechos reservados <span>|</span> <a href="mailto:info@rosasusaeta.com">info@rosasusaeta.com</a> <span>|</span><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/rosa-susaeta/50/1aa/134"><img src="./_img/footer/logo.linked.png"></a> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/rosa.susaetasalichs"><img src="./_img/footer/logo.facebook.png"></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>  
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking I'm not sure if this is best practice, but I would just do something with relative positioning in CSS. e.g.

```
img {
     position: relative;
     top: 10px; /* tweak until correct */
}
```

Comment: perfect! This is what I was searching for!!! To understand it, could you explain me simply why do I need to add position relative to make it work? If I dont understand I will never learn...

Comment: Sorry, of course. 

It's pretty self-explanatory really. Position relative will allow you to position an element relative to it's "natural" position. All I'm saying in the code above is move 10px down from where the top of the image would _usually_ be, if that makes sense. 

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: thank you, the positions are still something hard to stick it in my head! Thank you, very clear